# jwplayer hls label is not working properly

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7

I have created HLS streaming, it is working fine for me except labels, I added custom hls labels but it is not working for me,  here is my js

```
jwplayer.key = "**********";    
jwplayer("container").setup({
    file: "Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8", 
    image: "************",
    primary: 'flash',
    hlslabels:{
           "2000":"1080p",
           "1400":"720p",
           "1000":"480p",
           "600":"360p",
           "460":"240p",
    }
});
```

m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1173000,RESOLUTION=1024x768,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
Videos/Streaming/hls1080m_Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=950000,RESOLUTION=648x486,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
Videos/Streaming/hls720m_Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=522000,RESOLUTION=426x320,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
Videos/Streaming/hls480m_Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=371000,RESOLUTION=320x240,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
Videos/Streaming/hls360m_Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=279000,RESOLUTION=240x180,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
Videos/Streaming/hls240m_Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8
```

In jwplayer it show me label like

[image]

Can anyone please tell me why it doesn't show my given hls labels ?

Answer (score 1):

Your lavels aren't correct.

You have to use for the BANDWIDTH this

`#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1173000,RESOLUTION=1024x768,CODECS="avc1.4d001f,mp4a.40.2"
Videos/Streaming/hls1080m_Videos_38_1200_1459854139607.m3u8`

the BANDWIDTH=**1173**000 
is `"1173": "768p" or "1173": "720p"`

I hope this help you